# Mootools/moocheck not updating the style if checkbox is programatically checked

Tags: jquery, mootools

I am using mootools & moocheck javascript libraries for custom checkboxes and radiobuttons.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/mootools.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/moocheck.js") %>"></script>
```

This works fine and shows the custom checkbox styles proplery. But if I set the checkbox to checked programatically using jQuery it dosen't update the checkbox style.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        FancyForm.start();

        jQuery('#changeIt').click(function () {
            jQuery('#checkthis').attr('checked', true);
            jQuery('#checkthis').attr('checked', 'checked');                
        });

    });
```

Comment: here is a link to moocheck [link](http://code.google.com/p/zoom-gallery/source/browse/branches/zmg_2.6/var/www/templates/admin/js/moocheck.js?spec=svn138&r=138). fireEvent did not solve the problem.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zoom-gallery/source/browse/branches/zmg_2.6/var/www/templates/admin/js/moocheck.js?spec=svn138&r=138#62 - you need to do `$("checkthis").fireEvent("click")` to trigger it - or call `FancyForm.select($("checkthis"))`

Comment: Thanks Dimitar, but for some reason it doesn't understand either ways mentioned above. For now what I am doing is accessing FancyForm.chks collection and retrieving 'checkthis' from it, then passing that searched element back to FancyForm.select works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added following method to moocheck.js for updating specific checkbox or radiobutton

```
updateSpecific: function (ctrlId, isChecked) {
    FancyForm.chks.each(function (chk) {
        if (chk.inputElement.getProperty('id') == ctrlId) {
            chk.inputElement.setProperty('checked', isChecked);               
        }
    });
}
```

And modified the client code like following...

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        FancyForm.start();

        jQuery('#changeIt').click(function () {
            FancyForm.updateSpecific('checkthis', true);
        });
    });
```